# How was this formula in my textbook was derived?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

How is this formula derived (it is present in one of the hundred pages of my textbook about physics and fundamental physics) [image]
In the case of a system of particles $P_i$, $i = 1, …, n$, each with mass *mi* that are located in space with coordinates $r_i$, $i = 1, …, n$, the coordinates **R** of the center of mass satisfy the condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The centre of mass is the point at which our collection of objects will balance if we put a pivot there. Let's call this point $\bf R$. The vector joining the point $i$ to $\bf R$ is simply $\bf r_i - \bf R$. The force acting at this point is $m_i \bf g$, so the torque at the point $i$ is:

$$ \bf T_i = m_i \bf g \times (\bf r_i - \bf R) $$

The total torque must sum to zero, because that's how we define the centre of mass, so:

$$ \sum m_i \bf g \times (\bf r_i - \bf R) = 0$$

and the cross product is distributive over addition so we can take it outside the sum:

$$ \bf g \times \sum m_i \bf (\bf r_i - \bf R) = 0$$

and this can ony be satisfied if:

$$ \sum m_i \bf (\bf r_i - \bf R) = 0$$

Comment: Where did you find all of that?

Comment: Where man? Where did you find it?

Comment: @user38763: I have a 30 year head start on you :-) It's just one of the many things you pick up as a long term geek. How and when i first saw this I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

That is nothing but the **definition** of the position ${\bf R}$ of the center of mass. Indeed it is equivalent to:
$$\sum_i m_i {\bf r}_i = \left( \sum_i m_i \right) {\bf R}$$ 
namely:
$${\bf R} = \frac{\sum_i m_i {\bf r}_i}{\sum_i m_i}\:.$$
The last formula is perhaps the most familiar one.

Comment: But how did we find this definition?Why did we defined it that way?

Comment: It is too complicated to explain here what is the reason for that (good) definition, sorry. There are so many good reasons you presumably will see in your physics course. For instance, if the center of mass is initially at rest and the system of points is externally isolated, though the points may interact, the center of mass maintains the initial position, even if the configuration of the points changes in time.

Comment: Just please write down the maths and I will understand through my course

Comment: Imagine an observer looks at the system far away. He can not resolve the fine structure of each object, while what can be seen is just a mass point. Then the question comes up where this point is located and we find that it should be R.

Answer (score 1):

"Just please write down the maths and I will understand through my course."

With respect, I don't think the maths as such is the issue for you. Both the above explanations give the maths. I'm just guessing but it seems to me you are not focussing on the right thing here — it's as if you think, "If only someone would write down the right formula for me then I would get it."

The point is that R is a DEFINED vector—it is defined by the equation given—but the real question is WHY is it defined that way, i.e. what is its intended meaning? I think that's what you are, or should be, trying to get at, and not just some mathematical expression that would seem to switch a light on for you.

The way to see this is to start with a very simple example, say of two particles with identical masses. Look at where R (as defined) is in relation to these — right in the middle, between them. Now vary one of the masses, double it say, and see where that puts R. To put it very loosely, in both cases it's the pivot point about which the particles would exactly balance.

Now extend this to three particles. You could make them co-linear to start with then move one out of line to form a plane triangle. But in each case look at the resulting R (as defined) and see that it is indeed the 'balance point'. You don't HAVE to do all this by drawing diagrams and writing equations but do so if it helps. Otherwise you could just do it in your head. But do it in whatever way makes you feel comfortable.

Now turn this whole exercise on its head and ask yourself: how would I go about finding such a 'balance point' for a general set of particles; what property is it of this 'balance point' that DEFINES it and tells me where it is? You'll find the answer is precisely the formula given. And that's really is the point (issue) here.

The general idea is that you make things as conceptually simple for yourself as possible until you 'get it'. For example, if necessary imagine the particles are fixed in a massless gel so that they cannot move. That kind of thing.

Of course, having said all that, I might be completely wrong in my view of your current mindset. Dunno. But that's my best guess. I hope it helps.